# List collections and XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, class, serialization, collections

Basically I have created a user interface and the user input is stored within two lists.

One class contains both lists and I am trying to use `XMLSerializer` to write an XML file containing those lists which are properly nested, by passing the serializer just the class name.

Each time I try to do this I get an exception:

> InvalidOperationException, there was an error generating the XML
>   document

How can I fix this?

Code...

```
//declared globally

className mInfo = new className(); //create an object that references the class

classTwo aInfo = new assessments(); //used in a seperate method in UI ignore for now.

//end of objects


//start of class - assume is has a constructor for now

[Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot]
    public class className 
    {

        public string mCode;
        public string mTitle;
        public int nOC;
        public string term;
        public string oModM;
        public bool hExam;
        //create a list to hold the data
        [XmlElement]
        public List<className> mList = new List<className>();

        [XmlElement]
        public List<classTwo> aList = new List<classTwo>();





//end of class

//start of writer...

 public void XMLWriter()
        {


           string filePath = "test.xml";


        // THIS PART CREATES THE XML FILE 

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(className));
         TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath);
          serializer.Serialize(textWriter, mInfo);
          textWriter.Close();


        }

//end of writer
```

Comment: Please could you provide your code

Comment: can't show you code - see e-mail I sent your way...thanks for helping :)

Comment: Well, it's not just only me to help you, if you post code in here, just simplified code to show your problem, you have opportunity to let other people to answer

Comment: Assume I have a contrsuctor for this class:

[Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot]
    public class className 
    {

        public string mCode;
        public string mTitle;
        public int nOC;
        public string term;
        public string oModM;
        public bool hExam;
        //create a list to hold the data
        [XmlElement]
        public List<className> mList = new List<className>();
        
        [XmlElement]
        public List<classTwo> aList = new List<classTwo>();

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post the code in a comment. And we don't need _all_ of your code - just enough to reproduce the problem.